# Right and wrong about services in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

Please correct me if I'm wrong (and add other things you think is correct):

Application services ...

- the (public front-facing) api of a domain
- responsible for loading and saving aggregates
- can access repositories and other infrastructure services
- is not part of a domains ubiquitous language
- should/could be a very thin layer on top of the domain (that mostly handles load/save of aggregates and delegates the rest to the domain)
- can contain pure read operations

Domain services ...

- the "true" api of the domain
- contains domain logic
- works only with domain objects (not infrastructure services such as repos and email-sender-services)
- usually contain code that orchestrates different aggregates
- is part of a domains ubiquitous language
- can depend on other domain services
- contains only modifying operations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of application services is correct. I see application services more as command handlers. Receive a command, load an aggregate, call the aggregate method and save the chance. One command is handled within a single transaction.

Domain services are used to do something that aggregates need but cannot do. Typical examples could be retrieving additional information from the outside world or doing some calculations. The app service doesn't necessarily know if the aggregate would need this or that information but it can resolve necessary dependencies and pass the domain service to the aggregate when it calls it.

In my practice, domain services are most often implemented as functions. Remember that domain services aren't exclusively used by aggregates. Complex value objects can perfectly use domain services for the same purpose.

In my book, I use a domain service to allow a [value object](https://github.com/alexeyzimarev/ddd-book/blob/master/chapter10/Marketplace.Domain/UserProfile/DisplayName.cs) to ensure that it will not be instantiated with text that contains profanity.

```
    public static DisplayName FromString(
        string displayName,
        CheckTextForProfanity hasProfanity)
    {
        if (displayName.IsEmpty())
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(FullName));

        if (hasProfanity(displayName).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
            throw new DomainExceptions.ProfanityFound(displayName);

        return new DisplayName(displayName);
    }
```

Hence that the domain service contract (a named delegate in that case) is defined in the domain,

```
namespace Marketplace.Domain.Shared
{
    public delegate Task<bool> CheckTextForProfanity(string text);
}
```

but its implementation is the infrastructure concern and is being wired on the application side.

```
namespace Marketplace.Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// PurgoMalum is a simple, free, RESTful web service for filtering and removing content of profanity, obscenity and other unwanted text.
    /// Check http://www.purgomalum.com
    /// </summary>
    public class PurgomalumClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public PurgomalumClient() : this(new HttpClient()) { }

        public PurgomalumClient(HttpClient httpClient) => _httpClient = httpClient;

        public async Task<bool> CheckForProfanity(string text)
        {
            var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync(
                QueryHelpers.AddQueryString("https://www.purgomalum.com/service/containsprofanity", "text", text));

            var value = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return bool.Parse(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're breaking the encapsulation/completeness of your Domain Model, specifically the DisplayName value object (and hence also UserProfile aggregate) because they now depend on "out-of-process dependencies", i.e. an external API, which they shouldn't. It should be better to call that API from the Application Service itself, and then just inject the result as a boolean parameter to the Domain Service. Check this -> https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/domain-model-purity-completeness/

Comment: The dependency is inside the domain model, and the implementation is outside. It makes the model testable (without any mocks) and frees your hands when it comes to replacing the implementation. That's what domain services are for. The service abstraction is also a port for which the outside layer should provide an adaptor.

Comment: Here's the reference: When a significant process or transformation in the domain is not a natural responsibility of an entity or value object, add an operation to the model as a standalone interface declared as a service. Define a service contract, a set of assertions about interactions with the service... Give the service a name, which also becomes part of the ubiquitous language.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your understanding of `Domain Service` is off the mark.

The right starting point is going to be chapter 5 of *Domain Driven Design* by Eric Evans, where he defines `Value Object`, `Entity` and `Domain Service`.

As best I can tell, Evans was basing his patterns on experiences gathered writing domain models using Java circa 2003.  In Java, anything that isn't a domain agnostic primitive is "an object"; while you could *implement* static functions, there weren't any particularly good ways to *pass* them.  You instead needed to wrap the function inside of an object.

So "Domain Services" are "stateless objects"; objects, because that was a constraint in passing them, and stateless because all of the mutation of the underlying data is the responsibility of the entity that manages that data.

In the text, I believe he uses the example of a tax table; an invoice needs to be able to calculate taxes correctly, but the tax code isn't owned or managed by an invoice instance; instead, that data is managed elsewhere, and a read-only copy is shared by all of the invoices in the model.

In the Cargo shipping example, Cargo need to be assigned to routes, but the Cargo entities don't manage their own copies of the shipping schedules.  Instead, queries against those tables are supported by the "RoutingService".

Coordination of entities, what Robert Martin referred to as [Use Cases](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html), is an application concern, not something managed by the domain services (as described by Evans).

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding, but apparently @Alexey Zimarev considers that, as the implementation is outside the Domain Layer, a Domain Service can still use it without breaking concerns...