# DDD Pattern - Repository and Service concerns

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I am working on a modern DDD pattern since a few days (.NET + EF Core) and I have a bit of an hard time to figure how to use correctly a service layer.

I do understand that repositories are there for CRUD related operation and services for more complex logic (like involving multiple entities).

Let say for User entity, all CRUD operation should go into a UserRepository. But things like authentification, access rights, should belong to a service.

So my question is, **should the service shallow the repository and expose CRUD operation through it. Or the application should simply use service or directly repository when needed ?**

Also, it's easy to understand why the repositories interfaces should go in the domain and theirs implementations in the infrastructure. But what about services ? Some operation are totally related to business logic but some of them are more dependent on the infrastructure.

**Could an UserService exist in different area ? Like in the domain and in the infrastructure ?**

Thank for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right and wrong about services in DDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968565/right-and-wrong-about-services-in-ddd)

Comment: User and authorization is a bad example. Authorization/Authentication is not a domain concern, but an application concern. Your authentication service will look differently in an mobile, desktop or web application. And its not part of the domain. In a domain you typically don't have users and instead have `Customers`, `Employees`, etc..